# Android application fails and stops after clicking a button

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

i started a small android application to learn. I placed an input text and button on the screen. That shows on the emulator. After i press the button(which has an onClickListener) the application cracks and tells me on the screen of the emulator : "The application... has stopped unexpectably.Try again" and i have a "Force close", which of course closes the application. 
I cleaned and rebuild the project a lot of times. i have no errors shown.(using eclipse)
this is the layout/main.xml:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/widget37" android:layout_width="247px"
    android:layout_height="282px" android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_x="38px" android:layout_y="130px">
</ScrollView>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/compactList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Compact List" android:layout_x="36px" android:layout_y="78px">
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/detailedList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Detailed List" android:layout_x="176px"
    android:layout_y="78px">
</RadioButton>
```

this is the activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShowStuffs extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button searchbtn;
private EditText input;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    searchbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    System.out.println("on click...");
    String searchedText = input.getText().toString();

}
}
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. Any suggestions are more than welcomed.Thank you .

Comment: Seems like you have yet to discouver LogCat. Window -> Show View -> 'Other' : Andoird -> LogCat In there you will find your crash message which should help you locate your bug. Use Log.d("your tag", "your message") to print stuff to logcat

Answer (score 2):

In your layout/main.xml, you need to declare the searchBtn

Something like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Search Button"/>
```

Update: I tried with following code with no error.

```
package com.dude.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class foo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button searchbtn;
        private EditText input;

        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            searchbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
            searchbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //System.out.println("on click...");
Toast.makeText(this, "clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String searchedText = input.getText().toString();

        }


}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/widget37" android:layout_width="247px"
        android:layout_height="282px" android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_x="38px" android:layout_y="130px">
    </ScrollView>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/compactList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Compact List" android:layout_x="36px" android:layout_y="78px">
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/detailedList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detailed List" android:layout_x="176px"
        android:layout_y="78px">
    </RadioButton>
    <Button android:id="@+id/searchBtn" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Search Button" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/input" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh, i am sorry. i forgot to place that code too, i did declare the button in the xml. looking in the error log i see this: assertion failed: ContentViewer must have a content provider when input is set. i am googleing a bit to understand what i did wrong

Comment: I'm not too sure about the error, but I updated my answer, you can have a try

Comment: hello. firstly thx for taking the time for this. i had to restart the computer to work. unfortunatlly i still don't know why i got that error, but now is ok. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a NullPointerException.

```
String searchedText = input.getText().toString();
```

Where the input gets its value?

Answer (score 0):

add this to both buttons:
 android:onClick ="onClick"